# Div changing using Inner Html not working

Tags: html

I am trying to change the div content Using Inner Html but It is not working

I have given the code in fiddle please check and correct anyone

I use function to change

```
<div id="divd"> <img src="images/A.Png" /> </div>
<button onclick='changeMe()'>Click It</button>
```

my fiddle code is here [Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsundar055/Y3uWV/2/)

Expecting a quick reply

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to escape your quote marks in the strings, and add a close parenthesis at the end of the first `if` statement's condition. I haven't event binding in such a way in a while, so I don't know what's up there, but I would recommend binding to the event handler via JavaScript executed in the `window.onload` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was your code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divd"> <img src="../img/logo.png" /> </div>
<button onclick='changeMe()'>Click It</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeMe() {
    var div = document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML;
    if (div === "<img src="images/A.Png"/>" 
        {
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = "a href='www.google.com'>Hello</a>"
    } else 
    {
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = "<img src="images/B.Png" />"
    }
}
```

---

Here are the problems:

- Replace  `"<img src="images/A.Png"/>"` with `'<img src="images/A.Png"/>')`
- Replace `"<img src="images/B.Png"` />" with `'<img src="images/B.Png" />'`
- changeMe function should be available on dom ready.

Believing other problems like the link being wrong, will be taken care of, here is an :

[UPDATED WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3uWV/4/)

Comment: I changed as per your comment @loxxy [UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsundar055/Y3uWV/18/)..

But the image is not changing

Comment: what link you gave me I can't understand

Comment: Thanks @loxxy but for a div containing many images how can i replace with other set ... My code link is **[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsundar055/Y3uWV/)** Kindly find out the problems

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not escaping `"` characters in strings.  Instead of writing

   ```
   "<img src="images/A.Png"/>"
   ```

   either escape the double-quotes with backslashes,

   ```
   "<img src=\"images/A.Png\"/>"
   ```

   or use single-quote strings

   ```
   '<img src="images/A.Png"/>'
   ```
2. You're missing a `<` from the start of `"a href='www.google.com'>Hello</a>"`.
3. Are you using HTML or XHTML?  If the former, don't use self-closing tags (such as `<img.../>` as they don't play nice with IE.

The above suggestions are what I've found from a quick look at your code.  I recommend you get familiar with your browsers development tools, as they will quite probably help you find out all of this for yourself without you needing to post your code on the internet.

Comment: @Spooky: I haven't tested, but I would assume it would.  The `changeMe` function won't exist at present because its code has syntax errors; fix those and I would expect the function to at least be called on a button click, if not actually work.